# intellij - change default font for Windows 10 version to San Francisco

Tags: intellij-idea, fonts, ide

Is there anyway you can change the UI font of IntelliJ on Win10(Segoe UI by default) to the San Francisco font used on Mac machines? I downloaded the official font package then extracted and installed SF fonts but in IntelliJ they all show up as bold(they still show up slim and normal in Microsoft Word).

Answer (score 1):

The UI Fonts can be changed in `(File -> Settings -> Appearance & Behavior -> Appearance -> Use custom font)`.

Make sure that `San Francisco` fonts are installed correctly on your machine. You can try to download them from the repository: https://github.com/blaisck/sfwin

Also, I would recommend you try to use `Monospaced` font. It looks pretty similar to `San Francisco` font.

Comment: I downloaded the SF fonts there but they all looked bold in IntelliJ. And can you put a link to download the Monospaced font you mentioned? (i don't find it pre-installed on my system)

Comment: Have you tried to use `SF Compact Display` variant? Make sure that you have installed all fonts from the repository `(SFCompact, SFMono, SFPro)`.

Comment: Do you have `Monospaced` or `JetBrains Mono` inside `(Settings -> Appearance & Behavior -> Appearance -> Use custom font)` settings?
It should be preconfigured with IDE.